# How to deploy two samba server instances on Ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: server, 22.04, samba, systemd, services

I've searched for information about this topic, but it seems to be a strange thing that almost nobody cares about.

I have found some old information, but either it is outdated or it is unanswered questions in forums.

I have tried asking to chatbots, but as expected, their answers are not correct/well documented.

I want to have one samba server for home use with different shares and read and/or write permissions on each one. And another one for read-only, non sensitive data (Like software, Windows ISOs, music, films, etc.), access from internet (opening a port 445 from outside to my internal read-only samba server 445 port), so I can access it from everywhere, without the need for SSH tunnels or whatever. In this second instance of samba server, I would only expose non-personal, non-sensitive data, and read-only access in all shares. That way, even if someone hacks my samba password (please correct me if I'm wrong) I would not loose anything.

I'd like to know:

- Is it possible in a single Ubuntu server to deploy two samba server services?
- How would I duplicate my ethernet port? I've already tried configuring my netplan file as this:

```
#This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd

  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false

  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [enp2s0]
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.2/24:
            label: "br0:0"
        - 192.168.1.4/24:
            label: "br0:1"
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
        search: []
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 192.168.1.3
        metric: 100
        on-link: true
      mtu: 1500
      parameters:
        stp: true
        forward-delay: 4
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
```

and I think I could use br0:0 to one service and br0:1 to the other service.

- How should I configure the smbd.service file (original), and the new smbd2.service file (new one)?
- Do you have any other advice / notes regarding my question?

Comment: Why would that require two samba servers? That can be done with 1 and 2 users and/or 2 directories. And no you can not use the same port for two servers. This has all you need: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Multiple_Server_Instances but for what you want it to do ... there should be no need for it: 2 users with different permissions should be enough.

Comment: Your question is sort of wrong: you should be asking about how to get the middle part of your question. This "different shares and read and/or write permissions on each one. And another one for read-only, non sensitive data". And not throw in things you expect to need like samba. Mind that samba only makes sense if you have a non-linux machine. Otherwise nfs is the better method.

Comment: @Rinzwind, I don't want to expose all my personal samba shares to everyone in internet. This is a securlty measure. Even I'm not 100% sure of exposing only the non-personal, non-sensitive readonly shares.

Comment: @Rinzwind, AFAIK, if I have two IP addresses in my server, each one can have a port 445 dedicated to samba server.

Comment: @Rinzwind, I already Saw that guide and its outdated. I was following It and I saw that It has another way of managing servicies or something like that.

Comment: @Rinzwind I usually use my samba shares from Windows hosts, It Is its main use

Comment: I will try another approach: installing an Ubuntu Server virtual machine with qemu. And then run a samba server from the virtual machine. Anyway if there's anybody who tell me a better solution it would be great.